# How to set value to variable for first run in android

Tags: java, android, variables, scope

Hi i have 2 activity (`main_activity` and `sec_activity`) when i go to `sec_activity` i run a `volley` request and get value and make a `Toast` to print `sec` variable (`sec` is valid and `Toast` print `sec` successfully) but when i want to `Toast` out of `volley` request `sec` is empty

if i back to `main_activity` and go to `sec_activity` again 2 `Toast` is valid

this is my code :

```
private static String sec;
//other variables
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_send_new_content);

    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest("url example",
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);

                            try {

                                sec = new String(obj.getString("sec").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
                                Toast.makeText(send_new_content.this, "in here is valid"+sec, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                //other values
                            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }}
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }});
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);

    Toast.makeText(send_new_content.this, "in here is empty "+sec, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

}
```

in this toast is valid :

```
Toast.makeText(send_new_content.this, "in here is valid"+sec, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

and in this Toast is not valid :

```
 Toast.makeText(send_new_content.this, "in here is empty "+sec, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

thanks for your help

Comment: I didn't really understand your question but the 2nd toast is valid when you go back to main and return is because you declared the variable sec as static (which is a very bad thing to do :) )

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `volley` by default handles requests on background thread, even you can't make a request on UI thread, `Toast` which is showing empty `sec` value is because it is not waiting for server response in which you are assigning some value to `sec`, it runs before volley's response callback method is called.

You should only proceed further once you have received server response if you are dependent on your server side data. You may also show some waiting dialog to user till then.